# fortune TO or fortune OF

Tags: grammaticality

I am trying to figure out the correct usage of fortune in the following scenario:

I had the great fortune TO begin my investigations...

or

I had the great fortune OF beginning my investigations...

Comment: What do Google searches for "the fortune of finding" and "the fortune to find" seem to indicate?

Answer (score 1):

"the great fortune" appears to function as a modifier that splits up your verbal clause. You can compare this to a split infinitive, or an example where an adverb is inserted after the helping verb.

This example is less clear since "the great fortune" is not an adverb, but it still functions as a modifier.

In this case, "I had ... to begin" is less confusing than "I had... of beginning"

"the great fortune" could be seen alternatively as constructed as a direct object to 'had', in which case:

- 'beginning' is an gerund object refining "the great fortune"
- 'begin' is a present tense verb in infinitive form that doesn't match the initial tense ('had', past tense)